# Worksheet selection change events and conditional formatting

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a selection change event in a worksheet where if I click a specific cell (for example G2 (5%)), then the rows with Col (Percent) > 5% will be highlighted. I can use conditional formatting to get the highlighted rows. However, if I now click a different cell (H2 (10%)), I would like to select rows with Col (Percent) >10%. How can I achieve this using the Worksheet selection change code.

[image]

Comment: `I'm trying to create a selection change event` where is this code?  Please [edit] the post to include it.

Comment: I am new to worksheet selection change code, so not sure how to start the VBA code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want to achieve

Comment: That's literally the docs for the `SelectionChange` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bernice,

See if this is what you're after.
I used a combination of VBA - Worksheet_Change event to do a recalc and a basic Conditional setup.

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim isect As Range

   Set isect = Application.Intersect(Range("$F$3:$J$3"), Target)
   If (Not isect Is Nothing) Then Application.Calculate
   
End Sub
```

This will force a recalc every time the selection changes and the new active cell is in the F3:J3 range.

Conditional Formatting Setup:

```
Applies to box: =$A$3:$D$16
Rule:           =$B3 >INDIRECT( CELL("address"))
```

Results  0%
[image: Results: 0%]
Note: the test uses greater than! If you want the 0% items highlighted use >=

Results 30%
[image: Results: 30%]

Results 91%
[image]

HTH